# Is almost transparent topic part of SE new features?

Tags: support, status-bydesign

I'm getting in Anime SE some topics which appears as almost transparent. Is this a new feature? I'm wondering if this is a new feature or if I have my browser hijacked by some spyware or something. I've had only this "feature or problem" here.

[image]

Comment: Can you give us a better idea of what browser you are using and if you have any extensions and addons installed? Try looking at the site in an incognito or private window to see if you can reproduce this issue.

Comment: Google Chrome Versión 69.0.3497.100 (Build oficial) (64 bits). As for addons, I have many about 20.  I dont know, do you want me to post a list of all of them? In an incognito window I dont see any half transparent topic

Comment: ok, I found what it was. By accident I hit the ignore tag for the dragon ball series tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found what it was. By accident I hit the ignore tag for the dragon ball series tag, and that makes the topics of that tag half transparent, at least for my reputation level (may be it completely hides them for users with less reputation?)

Comment: FYI, re: "completely hides", it can be set on the **"Ignored Tags" box (on the right sidebar) -  edit - Hide/Gray out questions**